# To contest (the fact) that?

Tags: phrase-usage

I was wondering whether in correct, idiomatic English, the construction "to contest that", with "the fact" being elided, works.

Let me give you a couple of examples:

> He contested that Jesus ever existed.
> Did he contest that I ever came to the party?

In each sentence you can supply "the fact" between "contest" and "that".

Comment: Your examples sound fine to this native speaker of American English. Note though, that (technically) one cannot contest a **fact**; what one **can** do is contest an **assertion** *A*… or even a claim that *A* is indeed a fact.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Why could one not contest a fact? If I say for instance « He contests the fact that the Eiffel Tower was built by Gustave Eiffel », how is this not working?

Comment: Intrinsic to the notion of factuality is its immutability. Facts are independent of our acquaintance with or acknowledgement of them. I guess your Eiffel Tower example is okay, but if its speaker has been careful with their word choice and thinking, then what they means is, “Even though the Eiffel Tower was undeniably built by Gustave Eiffel, for some reason he  disputes the proposition that Eiffel did build it, as certain as that proposition is.”

Comment: So what such a speaker would mean is “He contests the assertion, apparently unaware that the proposition is a fact.” Per John Adams, “Facts are stubborn things.”

Comment: Hello Paul and welcome to ELL. On this site, we can only ask one question at once, and your second question was probably off-topic for this site, so I've removed it from your question. Also, in English we use " ... " for quotes. The symbols "«" and "»" have no meaning in English, except maybe as arrows

Comment: In English, "fact" has [many meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fact) not all of which require objective immutable truth. For example in a legal context "fact" has a different meaning, as something which is asserted to be true but may be denied by the other side.